# login with facebook using identity toolkit fails for android version 4.4.2

Tags: android-facebook, google-identity-toolkit

I've implemented sign in with facebook using identity toolkit for android.

It works fine on android versions 5 and up but when running on android version 4.4.2 I get an error.

Instead of starting the login flow the following error is displayed in the browser:

'  Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.  '

I didn't implement a customized login flow so I am expecting to get the default login flow.

In gradle I have the following dependencies:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.1'
compile(name:'identitytoolkit-api11', ext:'aar')
compile(name:'identitytoolkit_fbv4', ext:'jar')
```

And the app setting in facebook developer console is : 
[Client OAuth Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPLQW.png)

I don't think the issue is with the app setting because it does work for higher android versions.

I will continue to explore this issue but any advice will be very appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After further investigation : This error also occured when using a signed apk (as opposed to debug mode where it worked)

As it turns out the cause of all this was the use of ProGuard.

After adding the following lines to ProGuard rules file:

```
-dontwarn com.google.identitytoolkit.**
-keep class com.google.identitytoolkit.** { *; }
-keep interface com.google.identitytoolkit.** { *; }
```

the insanity finally stopped.